# Java ID verification error : connector error

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I try to check if the identifiers exist but I get a line error

```
st = Connecter.getConnection().prepareStatement(query)
```

with the error : cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method prepareStatement(String)
  location: class Object

and in line

```
catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

with the error cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SQLException
  location: class Login_Form

here is my entire code

```
PreparedStatement st;
        ResultSet rs;

        // donnez l'username et le password 
        String username = jTextField_Username.getText();
        String password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField.getPassword());

        // requete indiquant si les identifiants existent 
        String query = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = ? AND 'password' = ?";

        try {
            st = Connecter.getConnection().prepareStatement(query)

            st.setString(1, username);
            st.setString(2, password);
            rs = st.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next())

            {
                // Show my new form 
            }else{
                // Error message 
            }


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

my connector page:

```
package javaapplicationhotel2;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author camil
 */




public class Connecter {

    static Object getConnection() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    Connection con; 



    public Connecter() {
      try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
      }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
          System.err.println(e);


    }
    try{
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel","root","");
    }catch(SQLException e){System.err.println(e);}
    }
    Connection obtenirconnexion(){return con;}

    PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String select__from_classe) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.



    }


}
```

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem:

`Connecter::getConnection` is not returning the `Connection` object.

## Solution:

Replace

```
static Object getConnection() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
Connection con;
```

with

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    return con;
}
static Connection con;
```

Comment: ty, but I encountered an error at "return con;" when I change it "non-static variables cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @MendosaHenry - I happened because `Connection con` was not declared as `static`. A `static` method can not reference a non-static variable directly.  I've updated the answer. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue/doubt.